# How do I extend an array with the Flow type checker?

Tags: flowtype, mobx

In a React project I'm playing around with the MobX library. One thing it allows you to do is to write your code like you are working with the primitives but under the hood MobX is doing some observable magic. I'm also using Flow in this project and am having a hard time figuring out the right syntax to apply to the MobX observable arrays which have at least two extra methods, replace and peek.

The TS file for this code is pretty in depth and I'm fairly new to typing. The TS file can be found here:

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/types/observablearray.ts

None of the syntax that I've tried in Flow will work, it is probably all pretty naive/ignorant.

```
interface ObservableArray {
  join(str: string): string;
  replace(arr: Array<any>): ObservableArray;
  map(mapFunction: Function): Array<any>;
  reduce(reducerFunction: Function, initialValue: any): any;
  peek(): Array<any>;
}

type MobxArray = ObservableArray;
```

or

```
interface ObservableArray extends Array {
  peek(): Array<any>;
  replace(arr: Array<any>): MobxArray<any>;
}

type MobxArray = ObservableArray;
```

Most of the time I get this error "Expected polymorphic type instead of type 'MobxArray'." I'm getting this error when I'm trying to declare the props for a component:

```
type MyComponentProps = {
    myArray: MobxArray<string>;
};

const MyComponent = observer(({ myArray }: MyComponentProps) => (
    <div>{ ... code ... }</div>
));
```

Answer (score 4):

I probably had this solution long ago but my ESLint config was complaining and I probably never flow checked the results of this because of the no-undef error.

```
interface MobxArray<V> extends Array<V> {
  replace(arr: Array<V>): MobxArray<V>;
  peek(): Array<V>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether automatic conversion of TypeScript .d.ts files to flow is possible, but if you look into the package itself, you will find all interfaces in .d.ts files in the lib/ directory, that probably makes the conversion easier (those are not on github as they are generated during build)

Edit: maybe you can even refer directly to mobx/lib/index.d.ts, the flow syntax for interfaces seems pretty similar.

Comment: Did mobx ever ship flow typings since this question was asked? I thought I heard they did but I can't find it in the documentation